# Terraform with VMware Workstation

Tags: terraform, ubuntu-20.04, vmware-workstation

### terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

- Reusing previous version of elsudano/vmworkstation from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed elsudano/vmworkstation v0.1.9

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

---

### terraform plan

Error: Could not load plugin

Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/elsudano/vmworkstation"
to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message:

This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol.

Comment: What's your question?